# Sql alchemy driver with spaces not parsing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, driver, pyodbc, dremio

I'm using the driver 'Dremio ODBC Driver 64-bit' however when I run:

```
engine = create_engine("""{}+pyodbc://{}:{}@{}/""".format(driver,uid,pwd,host))
```

with `driver = 'Dremio ODBC Driver 64-bit'` I get the following error (I changed it to uid:pwd for obvious reasons...)

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'Dremio ODBC Driver 64-bit+pyodbc://uid:pwd@localhost:31010/'

which I believe comes from the spaces. I've tried changing the Driver name to Dremio by changing the header `[Dremio ODBC Driver 64-bit]` in `odbcinst.ini` to `[Dremio]` but that gave the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:Dremio

so I don't think I did it correctly, maybe there's something else to change?

Comment: It is not sufficient to just have an ODBC driver and a copy of `pyodbc`, you'll still need a SQLAlchemy *dialect* in order to work with a specific database. SQLAlchemy has built-in support for Microsoft SQL Server (`mssql+pyodbc://`) and external dialects exist for [Microsoft Access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) (`access+pyodbc://`) and [SAP ASE](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-sybase/) (`sybase+pyodbc://`) so you need to check with the Dremio people to see if a SQLAlchemy dialect is available for their back-end.

Comment: Perhaps https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-dremio/

Comment: @GordThompson thanks didn't realise this existed.

Comment: @GordThompson Documentation seems quite sparse could you add an example of an implementation?

Comment: Sorry, no. I have no experience with that dialect and no practical way to test it. If you want support for that dialect then you'll have to get it from them.